# Uncaught TypeError for Array

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner working on a simple *Tic Tac Toe* game in Java Script. Each of the game fields is defined in the "fields" array. I want to have a "for" loop to change the value in the field to "X" on click.

Here is the code that I'm using, which gives me the following error message: *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of undefined
    at HTMLTableCellElement.fields..onclick* . The console log works just fine.

```
for(var b=0; b < fields.length; b++){
    fields[b].onclick = function(){
    console.log("content changed")
    fields[b].textContent= 'X'}
};
```

I don't understand why this is not working, while this works exactly as expected and changes the value of every cell to "g":

```
for(var b=0; b < fields.length; b++){
    fields[b].textContent ="g"
};
```

And when I use one field from the array, it also works just fine.

```
fields[3].onclick = function(){
console.log("content changed")
fields[3].textContent= 'X'}
```

Why is my code giving me the error message?

Comment: Could you post the HTML as well?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Answer (score 1):

Your index `b` is resolved to the value at the end of the loop when it tries set the eventlistener and textContent.

Try "let" instead of "var" (works for me with let).

`for(let b=0; b < fields.length; b++)`

Comment: Thank you ACD, works like a charm. Never heard of "let". Greetings.